# System Settings won't open Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, settings

A few days ago I noticed that the battery icon on the menu bar wasn't there anymore so I tried to fix the problem through settings but when I clicked on the GUI icon it wouldn't load so I looked up the problem online and tried running `unity-control-center` 
but the gave me the message`bus error (core dumped)`.

So, after reinstalling Unity-control-center and Ubuntu-desktop it still gives me the same error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

(edit): I mistyped and put 15.04 instead of 16.04 I'm using 16.04 LTS with the 32-bit version of Ubuntu.
(edit) The same applies to Rhythmbox and Amarok

Comment: Please upgrade to a supported Ubuntu version in order to receive updates (including security updates) and support (including support here). The currently support versions are: 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS, 15.10 (will go End-Of-Life next month), and 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I also face this problem, did you find out anything?